# Changing permissions to read data/anr files programmatically

Tags: java, android, adb, chmod

I want to read the ANR files in the /data/anr/ directory on my device. I have managed to push my apk file to the /system/priv-app/ directory, so I can list the anr files generated by that apk in my program, but I cannot read each file (there are currently 2). 
Their current permissions are set to "-rw-------" and when I execute 
`chmod 644 /data/anr/anr-name` using `adb shell`, the permission changed successfully to "rw-r--r--" and I can read them through my program. However, because it is unpredictable when they generate, I want to change the permission to 644 within my Android Studio java program.

I have tried:

- POSIX permissions

  ```
  Files.setPosixFilePermissions(path, PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rw-r--r--"));
  ```

  This caused my program to hang at that line.
- JNA chmod library using the CLibrary interface

  ```
  private static CLibrary libc = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("c", CLibrary.class);
  libc.chmod("/data/anr/anr-name", 0644);
  ```

  This caused my program to hang as well.
- Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

  ```
  String[] str = new String[3];
  str[0] = "chmod";
  str[1] = "644";
  str[2] = "/data/anr/anr-name";
  Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);
  pro.waitFor();
  ```

  pro.waitFor() returns 1 and pro.getErrorStream() returns "Operation not permitted."
- java.io.File.setReadable(boolean readable)

  ```
  file.setReadable()
  ```

  file.isReadable() returns false and the file permission has not been changed.

For the record, I have a rooted device. My min AND Target SDK Version are API 26.

I also cannot execute "su" in my program because when I tried, it gave me a "Permission denied" error.

I am completely at loss as to what to do. I just want to read the ANR files from my program.